# Unable to hide a HTML div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP with the following login form code:

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.loginFailed == true}">
    <script>
        show('login-failed');
    </script>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${sessionScope.userLoggedIn == true}">
    <script>
        show('welcome');
        hide('login-table');
    </script>
</c:if>

<div id="welcome" style="display: none;">
    <p style="color: green">Welcome ${sessionScope.user.userName}</p>
</div>

<div id="login-failed" style="display: none;">
    <p style="color: red">Invalid UserName/Password!</p>
</div>

<div id="login">
.........................
....actual login form....
.........................
</div>
```

In my JavaScript code I have written

```
function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
```

But, even when the user logs in and when the `userLoggedIn` attribute is found in the `sessionScope` and even if the `<c:if>` test succeeds, if am unable to hide the `login` div. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `show` and `hide` functions are being *called* before the elements that they affect.

You should either move the scripts to be after those elements (simpler), or defer their execution until the end of the page (slightly more complicated, but generally considered "more correct").

Comment: Thank you very much.. You saved my life. I was very frustrated with what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

> even if the  test succeeds, if am unable to hide the login div.

The `<c:if>` is

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.userLoggedIn == true}">
    <script>
        show('welcome');
        hide('login-table');
    </script>
</c:if>
```

and the `div`'s id is `login`

```
<div id="login">
```

So, you probably need `hide('login');` in the `<c:if>1`

Comment: actually I have login-table id too.